# JDialog not showing minimize/close button on Linux

Tags: java, linux, jdialog

This question has been asked previously but from what I have found, the questions and responses are from a few years ago and hoping there is updated/new information.

The same code works on Windows as it displays the X in the top right corner.
On Linux, nothing appears in the top right corner. 
Windows is using JDK 1.8.0_60
Linux is using 1.8.0_111-b15

[image]

Based on the research, this issue is known to exist on varying flavors of Linux.

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class JDialogSimple{

  private JDialog dialog = new JDialog();

  public JDialogSimple() {
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setModal(true);
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setLocation(200, 200);
    dialog.setSize(400, 400);
    dialog.setTitle("Test Dialog");
    dialog.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
      JDialogSimple colourDialog = new JDialogSimple();
  }
}
```

Has any new information come about related to this?
Is this now the accepted behavior on the Linux platform?

Comment: This *might* also depend on the specific **window manager** that your Linux distribution is using.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the one thread that posts an answer has the following :

```
 super(null, title, Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
```

I think it should have been the following :

```
 super(null, title, Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

For my test, changing the above from MODELESS to APPLICATION_MODAL, the Linux JDialog now showed the X to close the window.